# How to use an Excel file (.xlsx) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, excel

So I have an Excel file where I want to use built in Excel features such as restrict data type in columns etc. but I want to use QGIS to display the data.

- I know that I can change it to a CSV file and import it
- I know that I can use the spreadsheet layer plugin to create a copy with the data etc.

But I want to be able to have the Excel file linked to QGIS and that changes I do in Excel appears in QGIS. [This is the answer that I got me closest (I think)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344762/68885). But I can't tell the virtual layer that the first row in Excel contains headers and I have some issue getting the virtual layer to work with my Excel file.

Comment: What's wrong with the spreadsheet layer plugin ? I did use it and it directly create geometry from XY or WKT field. Also it did not create a copy of the data but keep a link. If you modify the excel file you just need to refresh the attribute table in QGIS (after saving in Excel) to see the change. (By modifying I mean changing the attribute, adding or removing column will break the layer in QGIS)

Comment: Well yeah, it kind of works but sometimes I can't open the file with write access in Excel if it is open in QGIS and sometimes I need to close the file in Excel to get the layer på load in QGIS etc.